# Issue with Custom Post Types and Single

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type with custom taxonomies. I can get the list of posts to show from the main to the taxonomies (including the subs), but I can't get the single post to show. I've tried to make single-news.php, which didn't do anything. Still get the "Not found" message.

```
function news_post_init()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x('News', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name'         => _x('News', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name'             => __('News', 'text_domain'),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __('News', 'text_domain'),
        'archives'              => __('News Archives', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Item:', 'text_domain'),
        'all_items'             => __('All Items', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Item', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item'              => __('New Item', 'text_domain'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Item', 'text_domain'),
        'update_item'           => __('Update Item', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item'             => __('View Item', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Item', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found'             => __('Not found', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Not found in Trash', 'text_domain'),
        'featured_image'        => __('Featured Image', 'text_domain'),
        'set_featured_image'    => __('Set featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'use_featured_image'    => __('Use as featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'insert_into_item'      => __('Insert into item', 'text_domain'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list'            => __('Items list', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'text_domain'),
        'filter_items_list'     => __('Filter items list', 'text_domain'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __('News', 'text_domain'),
        'description'         => __('News Item', 'text_domain'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 2,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite'             => array('slug'         => 'news')
    );

    register_post_type('news', $args);
    /** Kill This After */
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('init', 'news_post_init');


function news_categories()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x('News Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name'              => _x('News Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name'                  => __('Categories', 'text_domain'),
        'all_items'                  => __('All Items', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item'                => __('Parent Item', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent Item:', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item_name'              => __('New Item Name', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item'               => __('Add New Item', 'text_domain'),
        'edit_item'                  => __('Edit Item', 'text_domain'),
        'update_item'                => __('Update Item', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item'                  => __('View Item', 'text_domain'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate items with commas', 'text_domain'),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove items', 'text_domain'),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used', 'text_domain'),
        'popular_items'              => __('Popular Items', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items'               => __('Search Items', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found'                  => __('Not Found', 'text_domain'),
        'no_terms'                   => __('No items', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list'                 => __('Items list', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __('Items list navigation', 'text_domain'),
    );
    $args   = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud'     => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug'         => 'news',
                                     'hierarchical' => true)
    );
    register_taxonomy('news_categories', array('news'), $args);

}

add_action('init', 'news_categories', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite slugs for the News post type and News Category taxonomy are conflicting. Change the rewrite argument for the taxonomy to:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news-category',
```